# Google Map and Marker Listener Issue (using Angular)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, listener

I've got an issue using GMap and Angular but first, let me explain my issue :

- My markers are correctly set on the map
- When I click on a marker I want to push the $scope.details array to use it in my view (see below)
- Basically, I'm coding my own infowindow to display partners details on a sidebar on the right (instead of displaying it on the map)
- My problem is that whenever I click on a marker, it's only pushing to $scope.details the last index in the loop

Now, let me share with you some code :

**Map initialization (centered on France FYI):**

```
var map = null,
    markers = [];
$scope.details = [];

function initializeMap() {
    var mapOptions = {
      center: { lat: 46.52863469527167, lng: 2.43896484375},
      zoom: 5
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
        mapOptions);

    setMarkers(map, partners);
}
```

**Partners info to be placed on the map**

```
var partners = [
        {
            'title' : 'Partenaire 1', 
            'lat' : 46.52863469527167, 
            'lng' : 2.43896484375,
            'type' : 'Distributeur'
        },
        {
            'title' : 'Partenaire 2', 
            'lat' : 47.52863469527167, 
            'lng' : 3.43896484375,
            'type' : 'Fabricant'
        },
        {
            'title' : 'Partenaire 3', 
            'lat' : 46, 
            'lng' : 5,
            'type' : 'Fabricant'
        }
    ];
```

**Setting up markers on the map**

```
function setMarkers(map, locations) {

        for (var i in locations) { // Looping through given locations (ie through partners array)
            var location = locations[i];
            var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(location.lat, location.lng);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatLng,
                map: map,
                title: location.title
            });
            markers.push(marker); // Pushing markers in their own array for later purpose
            marker.setMap(map); // Setting the marker on the map

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() { // Adding click listener on the marker
                $scope.details.push(location); // Pushing the clicked marker details
                // The line above is only pushing the last index in the loop
                $scope.$apply(); // Applying changes (needed in my case)
            });
        }
    };
```

**View code :**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <div style="height:500px; width: 100%; position: relative"> 
            <div id="map-canvas"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3">
        <pre>{{details}}</pre>
        <div class="well" ng-repeat="d in details track by $index">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" ng-click="removeDetail($index)"></span>
            <p>{{d.title}}</p>
            <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="localize(details[$index])">Localiser</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I can't find whatever I'm doing wrong and I hope you guys will help me with this ! 
Many thanks in advance.

PS : Don't expect a fast answer from me since I'll be away for a few days

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
for (var i in locations) { // Looping through given locations (ie through partners array)
    var location = locations[i];
    ...

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() { 
        $scope.details.push(location); 
    });
}
```

You loop over all your markers, updating a variable called `location`.   Each marker has its own event listener, which then uses `location`... however that's not the version created inside your for loop at every iteration, it's whatever `location` is when the user clicks the marker, i.e. the value it has at the very end of your for loop.

One quick fix here would be to simply add that location as a custom property to each marker, that you can then refer to in your event listener, e.g.

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng,
    map: map,
    title: location.title,
    location: location
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    $scope.details.push(this.location); 
});
```